# How Do I Create a Custom Block Helper in Spacebars?

Tags: html, meteor, spacebars

I want to write a custom template like this:

```
{{# myTemplate }}
    <div> some HTML goes here </div>
{{/myTemplate }}
```

Is this even possible? If not, what's the next best thing?

Use case: a bunch of buttons on a side bar. Buttons have different HTML content: some have SVG, some font Awesome, one has a template, etc. All buttons have the same decoration that would be nice not to mix with the content.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/spacebars/README.md

> Custom Block Helpers
>
> To define your own block helper, simply declare a template, and then
>   invoke it using `{{#someTemplate}}` (block) instead of `{{>
>   someTemplate}}` (inclusion) syntax.
>
> When a template is invoked as a block helper, it can use `{{>
>   Template.contentBlock}}` and `{{> Template.elseBlock}}` to include the
>   block content it was passed.
>
> Here is a simple block helper that wraps its content in a div:
>
> ```
> <template name="note">   
>     <div class="note">
>        {{> Template.contentBlock}}   
>      </div> </template>
> ```
>
> You would invoke it as:
>
> ```
> {{#note}}   
>     Any content here 
> {{/note}}
> ```

etc.